# Using a variable as boolean to check if it has been set is nice, but what about undef?

Tags: perl

I like to use variable as boolean to test their definition, but I'm confused with this :

```
my %a;
my %b = undef;
my $c;
my $d = undef;
if (!%a) { print "a\n"; }
if (!%b) { print "b\n"; }
if (!$c) { print "c\n"; }
if (!$d) { print "d\n"; }
```

gives :

```
a
c
d
```

so where is b ? what interpretation ?

Comment: `my %b = undef` is equivalent to `my %b = ('' => undef)`. If you add `use warnings` to your program you will get a warning: *"Odd number of elements in hash assignment"*

Comment: You're right - perl shouldn't allow several interpretations of "= undef" for any type of variable .... thanks !

Comment: See also [Why does "Odd number of elements in hash assignment" condition cause a warning and not error?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1117094)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's instructive to use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to investigate confusing Perl data structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %a;
my %b = undef;

say Dumper $_ for \%a, \%b;
```

This produces the following output:

```
$VAR1 = {};

$VAR1 = {
          '' => undef
        };
```

So, your second example produces a weird hash which doesn't contain anything useful but which clearly isn't an empty hash.

If you look at [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values), you'll see it contains this:

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns a false value if
>   the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns a true
>   value.

And when you evaluate the expression in an `if` statement, it is evaluated in scalar context. So, as your hash has a key (albeit an empty string), it returns true in that context.

All of which just leaves us asking how we managed to create a hash that looks like that by running:

```
my %b = undef;
```

You initialise a hash from a list.

```
my %hash = ('a key', 'a value', 'another key', 'another value');
```

For (hopefully) obvious reasons, it's best if the list has an even number of elements. In fact, under `use warnings` you'll get a warning if you use a list with an odd number of elements.

So Perl interprets your code as:

```
my %b = (undef);
```

And it would give you a warning if you asked for them.

But if you insist on using a list with an odd number of elements, Perl will just add an extra undefined element to the end of the list. So your code becomes:

```
my %b = (undef, undef);
```

And as a hash key needs to be a string, Perl silently converts that first `undef` to an empty string.

```
my %b = ('', undef);
```

And that's the hash that you end up with.

Assigning `undef` to an array or a hash is almost never what you want. Don't do that :-)